# Best practice for managing form status in child components

Tags: angular

Is there a best practice guide on how the form status, enabled or disabled, should be managed in a child component?

I need to build a page that can be used to create and show user details. So, when creating a new user, I expect all components to be enabled and when viewing an existing user, I expect all components to be disabled.

The question here is, what's the best way to manage form status in parent and child components so that all components are in the same state?

I have seen lots of examples where

- The child component is given the form status as an input and it uses this flag to determine if it should be disabled. (This does not feel right as I am passing a form to the child component.)
- The child component adds all the form controls and the parent disables the form with the AfterViewInit hook. (This feels like a bad practice as the child should do its job and leave the form in the status it was given. But this also means that we have a single control component that sets the form status and we would not need the same logic for different child components.)
- The child component looks at the form status of the parent and sets all its controls based on it.

Comment: I think you should explain your problem a bit more specifically. What's the flow, you add controls to a disabled form, and want to ensure that the added controls are disabled aswell? Vice versa if the form is enabled, they should be enabled?

Comment: How about not doing it at all but keep form once place? What componets can do is render part of forms in plain parent child relation

Comment: @DanielB I have updated the question with my use case.

Comment: @Antoniossss That crossed my mind too but I decided against it because it would make 1 component responsible for too doing too much. Also, I think the child should be responsible for creating controls it needs, making it self-sufficient and reusable.

Comment: Beeing reusable doest meen that is has to do all the heavylifting around it. Keep form on top, pass parts of form down to child components. Thats how I am doing it usually and it works, its clean and testable and easy to maintain

Comment: At the end, you have pass complete form data on the top level which has unknown structure - so its not like you have separated form layers like you think you did.

Comment: This is a big topic. ngx-sub-form which utilises the control value accessor may be best option for you